# access TextBox And DropDownList Values from a class inside code behind

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-4.0, code-behind

i know i lack a base knowlage of the realtions between classes and inheritance

i find it hard to understand a simple thing :

a given `DDl` or `TextBox` could be accessed from code behind

```
int selected = DDLID.SelectedIndex ;

string userInput = TBXID.Text;
```

Now from a class that is placed in code behind :

```
public static class ControlsValue
{
   public static int UserSel = DDLID.Selected.index;
   public static string UserText = TBXID.Text;
}
```

i was trying to "Arange" my code so i will be able to reuse it in some other projects

...so i have moved all global variables related to the code in that class into the class
and what i can't do is assign variables with `webControls Values`

what is the way to do it ?

### update

a way i could think of is via parameter

```
public static class ControlsValue
{
   public static void getValues(DropDownList DDLID)
   {
        public static int UserSel = DDLID.Selected.index;
   }
   public static string UserText(TextBox TBXID)
   {
      return TBXID.Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: Reusable class should be free from all dependency. In your case, you can create a class and inject the values from the dropdownlist and textbox in the class constructor and access it like property.

Comment: @Tariqulazam can You please supply an example of how you access it from a class within a the main class as im my code  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a different class like this

```
public class ControlValues{

    private int_dropDownIndex;
    public int DropDownIndex{
         get { return _dropDownIndex; }
         set { _dropDownIndex= value; }
    }

    private string _textBoxValue;
    public string TextBoxValue{
         get { return _textBoxValue; }
         set { _textBoxValue= value; }
    }

    public ControlValues(int dropDownIndex, string textBoxValue){
         this._dropDownIndex = dropDownIndex;
         this._textBoxValue = textBoxValue;
    }
}
```

You can create an instance from your code behind like below

```
ControlValues cv= new ControlValues(DDLID.Selected.index, TBXID.Text);
```

Now you can access the DropDown index and text as

```
cv.DropDownIndex;  
cv.TextBoxValue;
```

Although I provided an answer for this, Please note:

- Remember the stateless nature of web application and the way you are going to use this.
- In ASP.NET, it will be inefficient to create an Instance of class to hold values of server control because those controls and their values are directly accessible from the code behind. Using this approach will be an extra overhead.
- If you are serious about learning re-usability, I would strongly recommend you to learn basics of object oriented programming. Once you have a good grip of OOP, you will see clearly when to apply OOP principles.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation I've moved from the thing that was hard for me to concur (C#) to asp.net using c# which is for a start, you know , i learned all i could then when moved to use c# on asp.net its like c# is only one of the workers , that left it's kingdom , Winforms . i hope you know what i mean , global variable that it's value vanishes on each load , it was hard to get the why is this, understanding it all ...